# Why does my cloud function send multiples of the same notification to the target phones?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

The problem occurs when my users sign in or out (all this does is change a child under each user in my database called "logged_in" to true or false). When they do this it sends a ton of new notifications to the other user's phones and I'm not sure why this happens. How can I get firebase to only send the notification once and then forget about it? Why does it even store/remember by notifications at all?

Here is the cloud function that I have deployed.

```
function Efar (distance_away, token, message) {
    this.distance_away = distance_away;
    this.token = token;
    this.message = message;

    this.getToken = function() {
        return this.token;
    }
    this.getMessage = function() {
        return this.message;
    }
}

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotificationAdded = functions.database.ref('/emergencies/{id}').onCreate(event => {
    return admin.database().ref('/tokens').on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var efarArray = snapshotToArray(snapshot, event.data.child('latitude').val(), event.data.child('longitude').val());
        efarArray.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.distance - b.distance;
        });
        var payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "New stuff :)",
                body: "Info given: " + event.data.child('other_info').val(),
                //badge: '1',
                sound: 'default',
            }
        };
        tokens_to_send_to = [];
        if(efarArray.length >= 5){
            //only send to the 5 closest efars
            for (var i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
                tokens_to_send_to.push(efarArray[i].token);
            }
        }else{
            for (var i = efarArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                tokens_to_send_to.push(efarArray[i].token);
            }
        }

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens_to_send_to, payload).then(response => {

        });
    });
});

//code for function below from https://ilikekillnerds.com/2017/05/convert-firebase-database-snapshotcollection-array-javascript/
function snapshotToArray(snapshot, incoming_latitude, incoming_longitude) {
    var returnArr = [];

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var distance_to_efar = distance(childSnapshot.child('latitude').val(), childSnapshot.child('longitude').val(), incoming_latitude, incoming_longitude);
        var item = {
            latitude: childSnapshot.child('latitude').val(), 
            longitude: childSnapshot.child('longitude').val(),
            token: childSnapshot.key,
            distance: distance_to_efar
        };

        returnArr.push(item);
    });

    return returnArr;
};
```

Here is my android login class:

```
public class loginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

        //button to get back to patient screen
        Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_back_button);

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                launchPatientScreen();
                finish();
            }
        });

        Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_submit_button);

        final EditText user_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_name_field);
        final EditText user_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_id_field);

        final TextView errorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorLoginText);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String old_id = sharedPreferences.getString("old_id", "");
        String old_name = sharedPreferences.getString("old_name", "");

        if(old_id != "" && old_name != ""){
            user_name.setText(old_name);
            user_id.setText(old_id);
        }

        // logic for the login submit button
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        final String name = user_name.getText().toString();
                        final String id = user_id.getText().toString();
                        // make sure there is some data so app doesn't crash
                        if (name.equals("") || id.equals("")) {
                            Log.wtf("Login", "No data input. Cannot attempt login");
                            errorText.setText("ERROR: missing username or id...");
                        } else {
                            // check and validate the user
                            checkUser(name, id);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

    }

    // Starts up launchEfarScreen screen
    private void launchEfarScreen() {

        Intent toEfarScreen = new Intent(this, EFARMainActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(toEfarScreen);
    }

    // Starts up launchEfarScreen screen
    private void launchPatientScreen() {
        Intent toPatientScreen = new Intent(this, PatientMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(toPatientScreen);
        finish();
    }

    // checks to see if  a user exists in the database
    private void checkUser(String user_name, String user_id) {

        final TextView errorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorLoginText);

        final String name = user_name;
        final String id = user_id;
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference userRef = database.getReference("users");

        userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new

        ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot snapshot){
                // Check if id number is in database

                if (snapshot.hasChild(id)) {
                    // check if name matches id in database
                    String check_name = snapshot.child(id + "/name").getValue().toString();

                    if (check_name.equals(name)) {
                        // store password and username for auto login
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("id", id);
                        editor.putString("name", name);
                        editor.putString("old_id", id);
                        editor.putString("old_name", name);
                        editor.putBoolean("logged_in", true);
                        editor.commit();

                        // update users info
                        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        DatabaseReference userRef = database.getReference("users");
                        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(loginScreen.this);
                        double my_lat = gps.getLatitude(); // latitude
                        double my_long = gps.getLongitude(); // longitude
                        userRef.child(id + "/name").setValue(name);
                        userRef.child(id + "/token").setValue(refreshedToken);
                        userRef.child(id + "/latitude").setValue(my_lat);
                        userRef.child(id + "/longitude").setValue(my_long);
                        userRef.child(id + "/logged_in").setValue(true);

                        //if all matches then go onto the efar screen
                        errorText.setText("");
                        finish();
                        launchEfarScreen();
                    } else {
                        errorText.setText("ERROR: username or id is incorrect...");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.wtf("Login", "FAILURE!");
                    errorText.setText("ERROR: username or id is incorrect...");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled (DatabaseError firebaseError){
            }
            }

        );
    }

    //disables the werid transition beteen activities
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: is it generating new token on every loggin

Comment: When they log out their token is deleted from the database and when they log in its added back again. So yes kinda? but their token seems to be the same everytime they log in to me.

Comment: so that will be the problem. I think you will be more likely to send the updates to all token save in database?

Comment: how you pushing token to server when they login

Comment: I guess I'm confused why adding or deleting tokens from the database would affect this trigger tho? This trigger is for the "emergencies" child.

Comment: I just push a new child onto the database under "tokens"

Comment: well I can help you in case of android app. but the code you have posted above is not understandable to me.

Comment: every device has a unique token generated by fcm and it auto updates when the new token is generated when the session is expired or token is expired. well there are several conditions where fcm generates new token itself.

Comment: I just added my login class code from the app

Comment: make sure it is updating User in databse , instead of creating new user on every loggin

Comment: okay, I'll try that. But is there no way to make sure that a token doesn't get the same message twice?

Comment: yes token will not get the same message twice. untill and unless same message is pushed twice

Comment: I don't create a new user each time, i just update their children like you said, but it still happnes